# Is it possible to create an AWS IAM Identity Center (f.k.a. AWS SSO) instance programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, identity-management

I'm trying to set up [AWS IAM Identity Center (successor to AWS Single Sign-On)](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/identity-center/) for my organisation, and my team has a strong preference for Infrastructure as Code (IaC) wherever practical.

While exploring solutions, I was able to set up an Instance with several Users, Groups and Permission Sets using the Management Console UI. However, now I have come to set up something more long-term, I can't find any way to create an Instance via either CloudFormation or the AWS CLI.

When looking for documentation, I found the [CloudFormation reference for AWS SSO](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_SSO.html), as well as the [AWS CLI reference for the `sso-admin` subcommand](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sso-admin/index.html). Neither mention any operations that create instances. Neither does the [AWS SSO API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/APIReference/welcome.html), which leads me to think programmatic access may not be possible.

- Is it possible to create an Instance through code rather than the Management Console?
- If it is possible, what have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Latest update from AWS:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/aws-iam-identity-center-apis-automate-access-applications/

Here's the Boto3 for it.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sso-admin.html#client

Comment: Ah, I see. The `Client#create_instance` method seems like it will do the job.

Hopefully CloudFormation and/or Terraform start supporting this soon!